# Construct a variable for consecutive events by individual

Tags: r, vector, character

Supposed you have the following data:

```
t<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)

i<-c("J", "A", "K", "P", "J", "A", "K", "P", "J", "A", "K", "P", "J", "A", "K", "P")

e<-c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)

m<-cbind(t,i,e)
```

I am attempting to use the information from t (time) and i (individual, character) to code another variable (b). This variable compares values of e among (or between, each t; time interval). The variable takes a value of 1 if e is 1 for that individual in consecutive time periods. In other words, it is an incumbency variable; recording naming to a particular post at a firm.

The desired output is:

```
b<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
```

My question is: How can I construct a variable for consecutive events (e; naming to a particular executive position) across time for individuals.
Essentially, I want to pair-wise compare values of e for each individual in each time interval pair (t1 w/ t2; t2 w/ t3, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr you can do the following:

    <s>library(dplyr)
    m = as.data.frame(m)
    m = m %>% 
      group_by(i) %>%
      arrange(t) %>%
      mutate(b = e == lag(e)) %>%
      ungroup()</s> 

*See below for updated answer*

This results in NA values for the first value for a given individual (comparing t1 with t"0", which does not exists). Your description does not make it clear to me what the desired output would be in this case.

Edit, based on the comment below, and rereading your question, this is possibly what you are looking for:

```
m = cbind.data.frame(t,i,e)
m = m %>% 
  group_by(i) %>%
  arrange(t) %>%
  mutate(b = as.numeric(e + lag(e) == 2),
         b = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(b), e, b))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I think you might have meant to remove the `e == ` from `mutate` to get numeric values otherwise don't you create logical values

Comment: At the time of writing the question I was amivalent about the initialized values of e (for instance, assuming that 'missing t-1 was, either irrelevant or outside of the scope of my data and/or analysis; missing at worst... harmful to subsequent analytic interpretation & substantive inferences at worst).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Below, I make i a factor variable and set the levels to preserve the order.

```
df[, .(t, e, b=c(e[1], shift(e, type="lag")[-1])), by=i][order(t, i)]
    i t e b
 1: J 1 1 1
 2: A 1 0 0
 3: K 1 0 0
 4: P 1 0 0
 5: J 2 1 1
 6: A 2 1 0
 7: K 2 0 0
 8: P 2 0 0
 9: J 3 0 1
10: A 3 1 1
11: K 3 1 0
12: P 3 0 0
13: J 4 0 0
14: A 4 1 1
15: K 4 0 1
16: P 4 0 0
```

Here, `shift` is used to compare adjacent time periods, with period 1 filled in with the value from e. The by argument allows separate comparison of each individual. The second element of the chain re-orders the data to conform with the original.

**data**

```
df <- data.table(t, i=factor(i, levels=c("J", "A", "K", "P")), e)
```